# How to generate a random quaternion quickly?

Tags: orientation, quaternions

I searched around and it turns out the answer to this is surprising hard to find. Theres algorithm out there that can generate a random orientation in quaternion form but they involve sqrt and trig functions. I dont really need a uniformly distributed orientation. I just need to generate (many) quaternions such that their randomness in orientation is "good enough." I cant specify what is "good enough" except that I need to be able to do the generation quickly.

Comment: This is not a "random" quaternion, then.

Comment: @DoctorMohawk
Non-uniform does not imply non-random. For my use case in particular, "good enough" means that every valid normalized quaternion can possibly be generated.

Answer (score 17):

Quoted from http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node198.html:

> Choose three points *u, v, w ∈ [0,1]* uniformly at random. A uniform, random quaternion is given by the simple expression:
>
> *h = ( sqrt(1-u) sin(2πv), sqrt(1-u) cos(2πv), sqrt(u) sin(2πw), sqrt(u) cos(2πw))*

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, are these arguments in the order of "X, Y, Z, W" or "W, X, Y, Z"?

Comment: @Tara It is a random quaternion that can be interpreted as either order.

Answer (score 6):

From [Choosing a Point from the Surface of a Sphere](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177692644) by George Marsaglia:

1. Generate independent *x*, *y* uniformly in (-1..1) until *z* = *x*²+*y*² < 1.
2. Generate independent *u*, *v* uniformly in (-1..1) until *w* = *u*²+*v*² < 1.
3. Compute *s* = √((1-*z*) / *w*).
4. Return the quaternion (*x*, *y*, *su*, *sv*). It's already normalized.

This will generate a uniform random rotation because 4D spheres, unit quaternions and 3D rotations have equivalent measures.

The algorithm uses one square root, one division, and 16/π ≈ 5.09 random numbers on average. C++ code:

```cpp
Quaternion random_quaternion() {
  double x,y,z, u,v,w, s;
  do { x = random(-1,1); y = random(-1,1); z = x*x + y*y; } while (z > 1);
  do { u = random(-1,1); v = random(-1,1); w = u*u + v*v; } while (w > 1);
  s = sqrt((1-z) / w);
  return Quaternion(x, y, s*u, s*v);
}
```

Comment: i wonder how is it quicker then generate 4 random floats, then normalize the quaternion

Comment: @Avi It's not quicker, but it produces a uniformly-generated quaternion. Your way generates a 4D-cube and normalizes, so it's denser at the cube corners. (Or you could generate four Gaussian random numbers and normalize – that's also correct but slower.)

Comment: @Řrřola re: generating four Gaussian random numbers --- Gaussian numbers can be generated in pairs by sampling points inside a circle (see: [Marsaglia polar method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method)). But going from points in a circle to quaternion directly saves you some unnecessary logarithms ;)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to generate it, just generate 4 random (normal dist) float and normalize it if required. If you want to produce rotation matrices later , than normalization can be skipped and convertion procedure should note nonunit quaternions.

Comment: What is the approximate orientation distribution of this method? Does it cluster around certain orientations?

Comment: " I dont really need a uniformly distributed orientation" , if you generate random numbers in equal positive and negative (-N, +N) range , than distribution is good enough as approximate uniform

Comment: Well, not requiring a uniformly distribution is not same as wanting to know the approx distribution. Its not like 2D where I can plot the thing and eye ball it. Thus the question.

Comment: This is a horrible idea (I know because I implemented it and suffered the consequences).  The resulting distribution is heavily biased.  Here is a picture contrasting the right way (blue spheres) and the fast way (red spheres): https://imgur.com/fFLFdSw

Comment: This method is correct when the 4 random numbers are [normally distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

Comment: What the above comment said. Just as you can sample random complex numbers by normalizing two gaussian samples, you can do the same thing in any dimension, since the joint gaussian distribution is rotationally symmetric.

Comment: @dkoes Looks like you used only positive numbers. It is obvious, that numbers should be distributed both sides form zero. Normal distribution in zero is fine

Comment: Oddly enough, this correct answer (using normal distribution) with the lowest votes seems to be the simplest and fastest (at least on MATLAB) method.

Answer (score 0):

There is a matlab function randrot() to generate Uniformly distributed random rotations

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/nav/ref/randrot.html

The reference is "Shoemake, K. 'Uniform Random Rotations.' Graphics Gems III (K. David, ed.). New York: Academic Press, 1992."

On page 129, random quaternion can be generated from the
[Subgroup Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHVTz.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, the randrot( ) function is very slow for large batches! About 90x slower than the "normal" method mentioned above in my tests of 1 million batch size. Apparently MATLAB ensures that the random stream goes into consecutive quaternion elements, which means they generate a large random matrix and then explicitly transpose it (takes a lot of time). Then they turn it into a quaternion( ) class, which is also a slow process. Unless these details matter to you, I would stick with the "normal" method.